# Angular & Firebase - checking a node before subscribing to an activated route

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Firebase

**What I'm trying to do**

- Check a firebase node to see if a user ID is true / exists
- If it is, display a list of items from another node

**Issues**

- I have these two pieces of functionality working independently
- I can check a user node to see if they exist and write to the console
- I can display a list of items
- I cannot however, check the user and THEN display the list of items

**This is the code that checks a 'members' node**

This is what i use to see if the user key exists under members > project id

```js
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var pathToCheck = '/members/' + this.projectId + '/' + userId;

    firebase.database().ref(pathToCheck).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log('hooplar!');
      } else {
        console.log('hmmm');
      }
    });
  }
```

**This is how I display items**

```js
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((
      data: { issueListData: any }) => {
      this.issuesList = data.issueListData;
    });
```

**What I'd like to happen**

Ideally, this is the functionality I would like, but the following error is thrown:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'activatedRoute' of undefined

```js
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var pathToCheck = '/members/' + this.projectId + '/' + userId;

    firebase.database().ref(pathToCheck).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((
          data: { issueListData: any }) => {
          this.issuesList = data.issueListData;
        });
        console.log('hooplar!');
      } else {
        console.log('hmmm');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you add that as an answer please as it totally works :)

Comment: Ok no problem - done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't binding `this` properly change your then to arrow function to have access to outside scope `this`. Or at the end of your then function by the closing brace add `}.bind(this)` I'm assuming this.activatedRoute is your class prop right? This inside your then function refers to database promise not your class